# Ceph Installation : The repository 'https://download.ceph.com/debian-{ceph-stable-release} xenial Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: object-storage, ceph

I am trying to deploy a Ceph cluster, but got stuck as the `ceph-deploy install` not succeeding.

I am following [this](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/dumpling/start/quick-ceph-deploy/) documentation for installation.
But the `ceph-deploy install` not succeeding. Its giving the following error :

**[org-C][ERROR ] RuntimeError: command returned non-zero exit status: 100
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: Failed to execute command: env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBIAN_PRIORITY=critical apt-get --assume-yes -q update**

There is the screenshot of the error[image]
It says its not able to find ceph stable release for xenial.[image]
Can any one help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the the release in the url/repo. 
The repo is wrong, you have https://download.ceph.com/debian-{ceph-stable-release}
For example, if you want luminous, use "https://download.ceph.com/debian-luminous"

Answer (score 0):

You need to change ceph.list in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` from

```
https://download.ceph.com/debian-{ceph-stable-release}
```

to

```
https://download.ceph.com/debian-luminous
```